# AJAX not working with text box

Tags: php, ajax

I'm learning AJAX and created this simple code. I type in something in the text box and it should return with the word something pop up on screen. This was able to work when I clicked on a button but now that I changed it to a text box it no longer works. Here is the first file that contains the XML HTTP Request data and HTML code.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open('GET', 'test_ajax_return.php', true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="search" name="search">Type a name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="search_text" onkeydown="load();">
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the second file that I want to open when the user types in something in the text box.

```
<?php 

echo 'something';

?>
```

[SOLVED] : Thanks to Matt for Javascript Console. Found out some comments that I edited out effected the code after all. I didn't think HTML comments could do that. Lesson learned.

Comment: What happens if you remove `xmlhttp.status == 200`? Perhaps the server response is sending a different status than "everything's cool here".

Comment: Try `onkeydown="javascript:load();" ` or `onkeyup="javascript:load();"`. Also, make sure your input tag has a close indicator `<input ... />`. This way you have valid HTML.

Comment: What does the javascript console say? (F12 in Chrome, there should be a little red X icon on the bottom of the popup)

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for describing javascript console. Will have to use it now on. Found out that I had some html comments interspersed within the code I took out. Didn't think it was messing with the code. Much appreciated Matt.

Comment: Cool. I posted it as an answer. Can you mark it as THE answer?

Comment: @jason328  you try onkeyup (works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your javascript console (F12 in Chrome) and see if there are any errors (indicated by a red X on the bottom of the popup).

You most likely have javascript errors that you're not catching.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the code to my machine, it works perfectly.

As an idea though, maybe your browser's being funny about `onkeydown`. Try `onKeyDown` instead.